# Updated to Mac OS Big Sur and getting "Warning: Expected min height of view" errors in R

Tags: r, macos, macos-big-sur

I updated to Mac OS Big Sur last night and every time I open R or plot anything in R I get the warning:

2020-11-16 12:07:49.015 R[2217:9583] Warning: Expected min height of view: (<NSPopoverTouchBarItemButton: 0x7faf465ba2b0>) to be less than or equal to 30 but got a height of 32.000000. This error will be logged once per view in violation.

Any ideas? So far it hasn't prevented me from doing anything just pops up occasionally as I'm working. Let me know if there is more information I can provide. I've not had to post about non-code related questions here before.

Running newest version of R, but happened on 4.0.2 as well.

Comment: You should probably subscribe to the "r-sig-mac" mailing list.  Simon undoubtedly is working to make the MacOS version of R compatible with all the crap Apple forced on us in BigSur.

Comment: I have the same issue. I am a web dev (javascript and java).

Comment: Same issue on Electron JS

Comment: The same issue with Tkinter run in Python

Comment: Yup, same here! Working with JavaScript and I'm not even using the touchbar in my project!

Comment: same issue here with Plotly in R exporting an image with orca. I also get a javascript error that pops up in RStudio before this warning in the console.

Comment: Follow discussion here http://r-sig-mac.29524.n8.nabble.com/R-SIG-Mac-Problems-with-R-and-Big-Sur-td1290.html and here https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/1114

Comment: Same issue X4 with Python 3 + tkinter (2X, warning pops up, 2X more regardless of response to warning). My application seems to be running save that GUI won't display. I've noticed the touch bar will show buttons for the Terminal application some of the time (inconsistent), and I'm wondering if it might be related.

Comment: Just fixed it for my application. May not be the same for you. The brew installer apparently is incomplete and missing part of the tkinter package. Reinstalling from the official Python installer fixed it.

Comment: Same with wxPython in python

Comment: @KashanHaider Did you find anything as I'm getting the same error in electron app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step-by-step process to fix it:

- Updating brew by running these on your terminal **brew update** and **brew upgrade**
- Updating to the newer command line tools (CLT) **sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools** and **sudo xcode-select --install**
- Uninstalling macvim **brew uninstall macvim**
- Reinstalling macvim **brew install macvim**

For more information, check out this link: https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/1114